# Google Tasks API does not give update about Task completion when New Gmail Theme used

Tags: google-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

First I created a Task using below link:
https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas

Then I marked it as Completed. When I checked the API Response for the same using:
Services > Tasks API v1 > tasks.tasks.list [Returns all tasks in the specified task list.]
I was able to view the updates & found the task i marked as complete.

However when I did the same using New interface (theme) from GMail, I found that the task I updated with completion was not at all there in above API Response.

[image]

Thus Google Tasks API does not give update about Task completion when New Gmail Theme used. Is there anything I missed or is it bug from Google Task API with Newly introduced theme?

Comment: Reported the Same on Google issuetracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113870732

Answer (score 4):

I was held up by this same thing this week. but I just figured it out using the "Try this API" feature on https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list which I got to show me my completed tasks.  After looking at how their code told tasks.tasks.list that they wanted to be given the completed and hidden items (both flags were needed) I played around with my code and learned from error messages that after giving the tasklist ID, I could add a JavaScript object literal, so I copied part of object literal from the code of the "Try this API" and the following worked.

```
var tasks = Tasks.Tasks.list( taskListId, { showCompleted: true, showHidden: true } );
  if (tasks.items) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.items.length; i++) {
      var task = tasks.items[i];
      Logger.log('Task with title "%s" and notes "%s" and status "%s" was found ' , 
                             task.title, task.notes, task.status );  
    }
  }
```